# Animation aiming angle atan2

Tags: javascript, html

I want the bullet coming from the red square to hit the blue square wherever it is, but it doesn't go towards the blue square, what should I do?

I tried `Math.atan2(100, 100)/ Math.PI * 180;`and the result is 45° which is correct, but it shoots in the opposite direction rather than towards the blue square.

I'm confused please help, sorry for any mistake
thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title> just my game </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
        
        <script>
            /* LEGEND 
            
            red : red square 
            blue : blue square 
            Dim : width or hight (px) (dimention)
            posX : position on the X axis 
            posY : position on the Y axis 
            Inc : increment (known as speed) 
            aimAng : aiming angle
            
            */
            
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var redDim = 20;          
                var redPosX = 200;
                var redPosY = 200;              
                var redPosXInc = 1;
                var redPosYInc = 1;             
                var blueDim = 15;
                var bluePosX = 300;
                var bluePosY = 300;                 
                var bulletDim = 6;
                var bulletPosX = bluePosX  ;        
                var bulletPosY = bluePosY  ;                
                var bulletPosXInc;
                var bulletPosYInc;
                var aimAng; 
                var bullet = false; 
                
            //filling the canvas 
        
                    animate();          
                
                function animate () {       
                    setInterval(print, 25);
   
                }   
                function print () {
                
                //clearing the canvas 
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    
                //printing the canvas 
                    context.fillStyle="#c1d9ff";
                    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                    
                    
                //printing red square   
                    context.fillStyle="red";                
                    context.fillRect(redPosX, redPosY, redDim, redDim);             
                                
                //printing blue square  
                    context.fillStyle="blue";
                    context.fillRect(bluePosX, bluePosY, blueDim, blueDim);
                    
                //calculating the aiming angle between the two squares  
                    aimAng = Math.atan2(redPosY - bluePosY, redPosX - bluePosX) / Math.PI * 180;
                    
                //calculating the increment of the position of the bullet (if the bullet is not active)         
                    if (bullet == false) { 
                        bulletPosXInc = Math.cos(aimAng)*5;
                        bulletPosYInc = Math.sin(aimAng)*5;    
                        bullet = true;  
                    }
                //printing the bullet   
                    context.fillStyle="black";
                    context.fillRect(bulletPosX, bulletPosY, bulletDim, bulletDim);
                    
                //changing position of the bullet for the next print                
                    bulletPosX = bulletPosX + bulletPosXInc;
                    bulletPosY = bulletPosY + bulletPosYInc;
                        
                }   
                                    
                           
        </script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.sin and Math.cos take radians so you do not need to convert the result into degrees! So ignore the * 180 / PI bit

For a smoother and more efficient way for animating, try calling the animation frame when the system is ready to paint the frame. use

```
 window.requestAnimationFrame(print);
```

Full code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title> just my game </title>
</head>


<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
    <script>
        /* LEGEND 

        red : red square 
        blue : blue square 
        Dim : width or hight (px) (dimention)
        posX : position on the X axis 
        posY : position on the Y axis 
        Inc : increment (known as speed) 
        aimAng : aiming angle

        */

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var redDim = 20;          
            var redPosX = 200;
            var redPosY = 200;              
            var redPosXInc = 1;
            var redPosYInc = 1;             
            var blueDim = 15;
            var bluePosX = 300;
            var bluePosY = 300;                 
            var bulletDim = 6;
            var bulletPosX = bluePosX  ;        
            var bulletPosY = bluePosY  ;                
            var bulletPosXInc;
            var bulletPosYInc;
            var aimAng; 
            var bullet = false; 
            var speed = 6;

            //filling the canvas 

                animate();          

            function animate () {   
                window.requestAnimationFrame(print);    
            }   
            function print () {

            //clearing the canvas 
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            //printing the canvas 
                context.fillStyle="#c1d9ff";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                    

            //printing red square   
                context.fillStyle="red";                
                context.fillRect(redPosX, redPosY, redDim, redDim);             

            //printing blue square  
                context.fillStyle="blue";
                context.fillRect(bluePosX, bluePosY, blueDim, blueDim);

            //calculating the aiming angle between the two squares in radians 
                aimAng = Math.atan2(redPosY - bluePosY, redPosX - bluePosX) ;

            //calculating the increment of the position of the bullet (if the bullet is not active)         
                if (bullet == false) { 
                    bulletPosXInc = Math.cos(aimAng)*speed ;
                    bulletPosYInc = Math.sin(aimAng)*speed ;    
                    bullet = true;  
                }
            //printing the bullet   
                context.fillStyle="black";
                context.fillRect(bulletPosX, bulletPosY, bulletDim, bulletDim);

            //changing position of the bullet for the next print                
                bulletPosX = bulletPosX + bulletPosXInc;
                bulletPosY = bulletPosY + bulletPosYInc;

                window.requestAnimationFrame(print);
            }   


    </script>

</body>
```